# How to show application boot loader page

Tags: flutter

During first application start on Flutter I see empty page for 3-4 seconds. 
How to not show this empty screen or better show screen without status bar with progress loader.

Thanks

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#updating-the-launch-screen